# Microsoft Information Protection - Apply Sensitivity Label using Azure Function App - SQLite error: 14 'unable to open database file'

Tags: sharepoint, azure-functions, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

Azure function to apply sensitivity label is giving the below error:

Error: One or more errors occurred. (Can't open database, check folder permissions. SQLite error: 14 'unable to open database file', CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile)System.IO.IOException: Can't open database, check folder permissions. SQLite error: 14 'unable to open database file'

I added sqlite.dll uisng Advanced Tools(KUDU) under the folder - C:\home\site\wwwroot\tools; still I am getting the SQLite error: 14 'unable to open database file'.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `CacheStorageType.OnDiskEncrypted` to `CacheStorageType.InMemory` fixed this issue.

```
var profileSettings = new FileProfileSettings(mipContext, CacheStorageType.InMemory, new ConsentDelegateImplementation())
```